# Error while KVM installation in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-center, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am receiving an error message when trying to install a KVM virtual machine. I have provide you the complete log message below.

I managed to install KVM file successfully in Ubuntu 12.04 version.

Details:

```
Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Gust OS(VM): CentOS
```

**Log Message is below:**

> Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu: at most 2047 MB RAM can be simulated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 96, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1983, in do_install
    guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1246, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1314, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3199, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu: at most 2047 MB RAM can be simulated
```

Comment: How much RAM do you want to give the VM? And what's the output of `free -m` ?

Answer (score 1):

Too few details. I can guess.
Maybe you are trying to virtualize a 64bit OS within a 32bit host.
And if your host is 32bit, "no more than 2047 MB RAM" can be virtualized as PAE couLd not apply to virtualization.